# Admin Posts Table Column Fitlering is not working for Custom Post Type

Tags: posts, filters

I have  lot of posts in my custom post type.  I want to filter it when I click on my post category. as like the following image. 
[image]

Here is my code to add it on click links.

```
function my_custom_columns($column){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom();
switch ($column) {      
    case 'ticketcat' :          
        echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticketcat', '', ', ','');
    break;
    case 'author_role' :
        $get_author_role = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        echo implode(', ', $get_author_role->roles); 
    break;
    case 'ref' :              
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'employer_ref', true); 
    break;
  }
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'my_custom_columns');
```

Now, If I click on Payment or Technical, it should show the filtered results of the selected one.

Comment: do you want to work the filter or search.?

Comment: I want filtering while click on the link, which I showed in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just echoing the terms list. So, it will generate front end path. You have to change like this .

```
$post_type= get_post_type($post->ID );
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'ticketcat', array("fields" => "all"));
echo '<a href="'.admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type ) . '&ticketcat='.$term_list[0]->slug.'" > '. $term_list[0]->name.' </a>';
```

First get the post type and its term name and slug, than with help of custom echo, display the results. Here the complete function which you are seeking.

```
function my_custom_columns($column){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom();
    switch ($column) {      
        case 'ticketcat' :          
            //echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'ticketcat', '', ', ','');
            $post_type= get_post_type($post->ID );
            $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'ticketcat', array("fields" => "all"));
            echo '<a href="'.admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=' . $post_type ) . '&ticketcat='.$term_list[0]->slug.'" > '. $term_list[0]->name.' </a>';
        break;
        case 'author_role' :
            $get_author_role = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            echo implode(', ', $get_author_role->roles); 
        break;
        case 'ref' :              
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'employer_ref', true); 
        break;
    }
}
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column',  'my_custom_columns');
```

Comment: let me check it